# FFMPEG - Images to Video

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 15 -i images/img%03d.jpg -vcodec libx264 video.mp4
```

I run this code with exec in php.

I am not getting the output. The video.mp4 is blank.

However if i modify this commade to something like this,

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i i.jpg -vcodec libx264 -t 15 video.mp4
```

The video is running for 15 seconds.

I tried **-r 1/15**. It is not working too.
Where do i do the mistake?

```
<?php
$command = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f image2 -r 15 -i images/img%03d.jpg -vcodec libx264 video.mp4";
exec($command);
?>
```

images folder has img001.jpg img002.jpg ... img005.jpg

```
Array
(
[0] => ffmpeg version N-48645-gf3c9d8d Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
[1] =>   built on Jan  9 2013 04:08:32 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
[2] =>   configuration: --extra-cflags=-I../static/include --extra-ldflags='-L../static/lib -static' --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-x11grab --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libxavs --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-ffserver
[3] =>   libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
[4] =>   libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
[5] =>   libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
[6] =>   libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
[7] =>   libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
[8] =>   libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
[9] =>   libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
[10] =>   libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[11] => Input #0, image2, from 'images/img%03d.jpg':
[12] =>   Duration: 00:00:45.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
[13] =>     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 200x300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:3], 0.07 fps, 0.33 tbr, 0.07 tbn, 0.07 tbc
[14] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] using SAR=1/1
[15] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[16] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] profile High, level 1.2
[17] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] 264 - core 129 r2230 1cffe9f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[18] => Output #0, mp4, to 'videos/video.mp4':
[19] =>   Metadata:
[20] =>     encoder         : Lavf54.59.106
[21] =>     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p, 200x300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:3], q=-1--1, 16384 tbn, 0.07 tbc
[22] => Stream mapping:
[23] =>   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libx264)
[24] => Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[25] => Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:200x300 fmt:yuvj420p to size:200x300 fmt:yuvj444p
[26] => frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      43kB time=00:00:15.00 bitrate=  23.2kbits/s
[27] => video:42kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.912722%
[28] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] frame I:1     Avg QP:18.97  size: 13250
[29] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] frame P:2     Avg QP:18.68  size: 14368
[30] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] mb I  I16..4:  0.8% 81.4% 17.8%
[31] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] mb P  I16..4:  0.0% 84.8% 15.2%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
[32] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] 8x8 transform intra:83.7%
[33] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 96.4% 99.2% 97.6%
[34] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] i16 v,h,dc,p:  0%  0% 100%  0%
[35] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 18% 13%  5%  8% 11%  8% 10%  7%
[36] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 14%  9%  7%  9% 13%  8%  7%  7%
[37] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 17% 26% 12%
[38] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[39] => [libx264 @ 0x3283080] kb/s:7.46
```

)

Comment: Does your file name really have a percent sign in it?

Comment: Please post the PHP, since the quoting is singificant

Comment: I added the PHP script in the question

Comment: try replacing " with ' and/or runing your command in shell.

Comment: i created one video for every image and then i joined them. Atleaset there is a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

try using

-loop 1

and

-r 1/4

and see what u get then

Comment: If i add -loop 1, the script is not finishing its execution. The page keeps loading for very long time. -r 1/4 alone is not producing the video. I test that mp4 in vlc. It is not running.

Comment: Duration: 00:00:12.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A : bitrate is N/A. Could it be a problem?

Comment: I gave you 1 point for the answer, because they are the most important options to create slideshow. But they are not working!!!

Comment: sample at : http://pastebin.com/1gCnGKiw      YOU MUST USE "-t" along WITH EARLIER SUGGESTION. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the frame rate for both input (before -i) and output (before the output file name) only reliably works when you use raw input files, such as h.264 bitstreams, where you explicitly need to tell FFmpeg what frame rate you expect.

The actual option you should use for image2 is -framerate:

ffmpeg  -framerate 25 -i thum-%04d.jpg -r 25 -c:v libx264 out1.mp4